# The app keeps returning to previous activity even when i finished it

Tags: android, kotlin

The navigation isn't working for some reason

I have an app with 2 activities, 1 is the login activity, and the other is the home activity, when i login, i show the home activity, but the problem is that when i press back button on the phone, the home activity returns to home activity, the other problem, is that when i logout, i finish the home activity and show the login activity again, but for some reason when i press back button, it returns to home activity, i have tried "finish()" i have tried intent flags, and nothing seems to work, i'll leave my code below:

Login function

```
fun login(){
    //AsyncLogin().execute()
    val manager = DataManager()
    var login = LoginModel()
    login.idSucursal = sucursalTextfield.text.toString()
    login.password = passwordTextfield.text.toString()
    val loginContext = this
    manager.login(login, this){
        val result = it
        if(result.messageType == 1){
            val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            this.progressHud.dismiss()
            this.finish()

            System.out.println("Se Guardo el login")
        }else{
            //Mostrar alerta
            alert(result.message) {
                title = "Aviso"
                positiveButton("Aceptar"){}
            }.show().apply {
                getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)?.let { it.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE) }
                getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)?.let { it.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff33b5e5")) }
            }
            this.progressHud.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Logout Function in Home Activity

```
try {
                SharedData.SharedInstance.realmInstance.beginTransaction()
                SharedData.SharedInstance.realmInstance.deleteAll()
                SharedData.SharedInstance.realmInstance.commitTransaction()
                val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                this.finish()
            }catch(e:Exception){
                System.out.println(e.localizedMessage)
            }
```

Comment: Your app must be crashing on back pressed and restarts itself, Goto Logcat, in the app dropdown selection, you might find your app package with **[DEAD]** at the end

Comment: and what about when i logout? when i logout it shows the login activity again, but when i press back it returns to home activity instead of closing the app

Comment: Also, I have checked Logcat now, it doesn't show the dead thing

Comment: What do you mean by this statement "when i press back button on the phone, the home activity returns to home activity"

Comment: its just as you read, I login, the home activity is shown, i press back button, the animation of the back is show, the home activity goes down, to show.... the home activity!!

Comment: Which activity is your launcher activity?

Comment: heres a link to a video of whats happening:
https://webm.red/Nfsx.webm

Comment: the launcher activity is the login activity

Comment: Also, this is the logout bug https://webm.red/lusA.webm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, apparently, the app kept making instances of my home activity, so i added this in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    </activity>
```

the singleInstance line resolved my issue

Comment: Please accept your answer, it will help future visitors.

Comment: i tried, but stack overflow showed me a message that i couldn't accept it until 2 days passed, thats why i didn't accepted it before